# search for pattern in text using wildcards and automatically export the matches

Tags: search, macros, libreoffice, thunderbird

I've been trying to use Thunderbird with expression search and ImportExportTools Add-on to look for a specific pattern in my emails, which worked to some degree at least. But now I'm unable to create a rule which would export the matches (and not any text before and after the pattern I searched for). I also tried using Libreoffice Calc but it's taking much longer to search and freezes doing so plus it also marks the whole line in which the pattern I searched for is found. I'd be really glad if anyone could help me out by suggesting a way to achieve my goal!

Answer (score 0):

Expresso by Ultrapico Editor regex search does the trick